# Down-sampling specific period on dataframe using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, downsampling

I have a long time serie that starts in 1963 and ends in 2013. However, from 1963 til 2007 it has an hourly sampling period while after 2007's sampling rate changes to 5 minutes. Is it possible to resample data just after 2007 in a way that the entire time serie has hourly data sampling? Data slice below.

```
yr, m, d, h, m, s, sl
2007, 11, 30, 19, 0, 0, 2180
2007, 11, 30, 20, 0, 0, 2310
2007, 11, 30, 21, 0, 0, 2400
2007, 11, 30, 22, 0, 0, 2400
2007, 11, 30, 23, 0, 0, 2270
2008, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2210
2008, 1, 1, 0, 5, 0, 2210
2008, 1, 1, 0, 10, 0, 2210
2008, 1, 1, 0, 15, 0, 2200
2008, 1, 1, 0, 20, 0, 2200
2008, 1, 1, 0, 25, 0, 2200
2008, 1, 1, 0, 30, 0, 2200
2008, 1, 1, 0, 35, 0, 2200
2008, 1, 1, 0, 40, 0, 2200
2008, 1, 1, 0, 45, 0, 2200
2008, 1, 1, 0, 50, 0, 2200
2008, 1, 1, 0, 55, 0, 2200
2008, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2190
2008, 1, 1, 1, 5, 0, 2190
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give your dataframe proper column names

```
df.columns = 'year month day hour minute second sl'.split()
```

**Solution**

```
df.groupby(['year', 'month', 'day', 'hour'], as_index=False).first()

   year  month  day  hour  minute  second    sl
0  2007     11   30    19       0       0  2180
1  2007     11   30    20       0       0  2310
2  2007     11   30    21       0       0  2400
3  2007     11   30    22       0       0  2400
4  2007     11   30    23       0       0  2270
5  2008      1    1     0       0       0  2210
6  2008      1    1     1       0       0  2190
```

---

**Option 2**
Here is an option that builds off of the column renaming.  We'll use `pd.to_datetime` to cleverly get at our dates, then use `resample`.  However, you have time gaps and will have to address nulls and re-cast dtypes.

```
df.set_index(
    pd.to_datetime(df.drop('sl', 1))
).resample('H').first().dropna().astype(df.dtypes)

                     year  month  day  hour  minute  second    sl
2007-11-30 19:00:00  2007     11   30    19       0       0  2180
2007-11-30 20:00:00  2007     11   30    20       0       0  2310
2007-11-30 21:00:00  2007     11   30    21       0       0  2400
2007-11-30 22:00:00  2007     11   30    22       0       0  2400
2007-11-30 23:00:00  2007     11   30    23       0       0  2270
2008-01-01 00:00:00  2008      1    1     0       0       0  2210
2008-01-01 01:00:00  2008      1    1     1       0       0  2190
```

Answer (score 2):

Rename the minute column for convenience:

```
df.columns = ['yr', 'm', 'd', 'h', 'M', 's', 'sl']
```

Create a datetime column:

```
from datetime import datetime as dt
df['dt'] = df.apply(axis=1, func=lambda x: dt(x.yr, x.m, x.d, x.h, x.M, x.s))
```

Resample:

For pandas < 0.19:

```
df = df.set_index('dt').resample('60T').reset_index('dt')
```

For pandas >= 0.19:

```
df = df.resample('60T', on='dt')
```

Comment: If you run this you'll see that you still need to handle the nulls from the gaps and dtypes of float from nulls.

Answer (score 2):

You'd better first append a datetime column to your dataframe:
`df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df[['yr', 'mnth', 'd', 'h', 'm', 's']])`

But before that you should rename the month column:
`df.rename(columns={ df.columns[1]: "mnth" })`

Then you set a datetime column as dataframe index:
`data.set_index('datetime', inplace=True)`

Now you can apply resample method on your dataframe on by prefereed sampling rate:
`df.resample('60T', on='datatime').mean()`

Here I used **mean** to aggregate. You can use other method based on your need. 
See [Pandas document](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) as a ref.

Comment: If you run this you'll see that you still need to handle the nulls from the gaps and dtypes of float from nulls.